# R - Use names in a list to feed named objects to a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, zoo, names

I have a data frame of some 90 financial symbols (will use 3 for simplicity)

```
> View(syM)     
  symbol
1 APPL
2 YAHOO
3 IBM
```

I created a function that gets JSON data for these symbols and produce an output. Basically:

```
nX  <- function(x) {
  #get data for "x", format it, and store it in "nX"
  nX <- x
  return(nX)
}
```

I used a loop to get the data and store the zoo series named after each symbol accordingly.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(syM)) {
  assign(x = paste0(syM[i,]), 
  value = nX(x = syM[i,]))
  Sys.sleep(time = 1)
}
```

Which results in:

```
[1] "APPL"          "YAHOO"         "IBM"
```

Each is a zoo series with 5 columns of data.

Further, I want to get some plotting done to each series and output the result, preferably using a for loop or something better.

```
yN  <- function(y) {
  #plot "y" series, columns 2 and 3, and store it in "yN"
  yN <- y[,2:3]
  return(yN)
}
```

Following a similar logic to my previous loop I tried:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(syM)) {
  assign(x = paste0(pairS[i,],".plot"),
  value = yN(y = paste0(syM[i,])))
}
```

But so far the data is not being sent to the function, only the name of the symbol, so I naturally get:

```
y[,2:3] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I have also tried:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(syM)) {
  assign(x = paste0(syM[i,],".plot"),
  value = yN(y = ls(pattern = paste0(syM[i,]))))
}
```

With similar results. When I input the name of the series manually it does save the plot of the first symbol as "APPL.Plot".

```
assign(paste0(syM[1,], ".Plot"),
       value = yN(p = APPL))
```

Comment: Surely you have failed to include calls to `library` for the various packages that are implied to be loaded for this. Also I suggest in the future you add output of `dput` applied to `syM`.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I believe the only library that is used is `library(quantmod)`, but that is only to get the data for the symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, you're calling yN with a character argument in:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(syM)) {
  assign(x = paste0(pairS[i,],".plot"),
  value = yN(y = paste0(syM[i,])))
}
```

`paste0(syM[i,])` is going to resolve to a character and not the zoo object it appears you're trying to reference. Instead, use something like `get()`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(syM)) {
  assign(x = paste0(pairS[i,],".plot"),
  value = yN(y = get(paste0(syM[i,]))))
}
```

Or perhaps just store your zoo objects in a list in the first place and then operate on all elements of the list with something like `lapply()`...

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I was trying to avoid placing them all in in a single list with `lapply()`. The key was to use `get()`

Answer (score 1):

Consider `lapply` with `setNames` to create a named list of *nX* returned objects:

```
nX_list <- setNames(lapply(syM$symbol, nX), syM$symbol)

# OUTPUT ZOO OBJECTS BY NAMED INDEX
nX_list$AAPL
nX_list$YAHOO
nX_list$IBM

# CREATE SEPARATE OBJECTS FROM LIST 
# BUT NO NEED TO FLOOD GLOBAL ENVIR W/ 90 OBJECTS, JUST USE 1 LIST
list2env(nX_list, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

For plot function, first add a `get` inside function to retrieve an object by its string name, then similarly run `lapply` with `setNames`:

```
yN  <- function(y) {
  #plot "y" series, columns 2 and 3, and store it in "yN"  
  yobj <- get(nX_list[[y]])     # IF USING ABOVE LIST
  yobj <- get(y)                # IF USING SEPARATE OBJECT

  yN <- yobj[,2:3]
  return(yN)
}

plot_list <- setNames(lapply(syM$symbol, yN), paste0(syM$symbol, ".plot"))

# OUTPUT PLOTS BY NAMED INDEX
plot_list$AAPL.plot
plot_list$YAHOO.plot
plot_list$IBM.plot

# CREATE SEPARATE OBJECTS FROM LIST 
# BUT NO NEED TO FLOOD GLOBAL ENVIR W/ 90 OBJECTS, JUST USE 1 LIST
list2env(plot_list, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I was able to do it with `get()` together with `paste0()`. I used the `for` loop mainly to `assign()` the name from the symbol list to each series separately. I think I'll reconsider using `lapply()` to bind them all together.

Comment: But your option with the _yobj_ using `get()` is way better.

Comment: As I comment in code, **one** list is much more manageable than 90 objects flooding your global environment especially if objects are same structure like *zoo* of 5 cols.